# Hexo - why can't I use nbsp to insert space

Tags: markdown, hexo

I just want to insert some space in a markdown file with "& nbsp;", but it doesn't work while hexo displays the page.

My code:

```
1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;8&nbsp;&nbsp;9
2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;9&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;12  
4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;7&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13
5&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;11&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;15
```

[The hexo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbz2l.png)

So, why doesn't `"& nbsp;"` work?

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k5Cp.png) and [rendered page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaLXe.png).

I'm using `hexo-renderer-markdown-it` and it can correctly renderer `&nbsp;`.

Comment: it really works,maybe the problem is related to renderer?

Comment: @XinBaBa I think it is.